# List specific AD groups with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, hashicorp

I have defined AD group names as `Variables` in `tfvars` file like this. So I will be creating the **Infrastructure Contributors** group and will be assigning  the `Devops_IAC_Administrators` ad group as its members. Same will happen to `Application_Contributors` group that I will create using terraform.

```
    groups = {
  "Infrastructure Contributors" = [
    "Devops_IAC_Administrators"
  ],
  "Application_Contributors" = [
    "Devops_IAC_Administrators",
    "Devops_IAC_Contributors"

  ]
}
```

I was able to return all the `display_name` I have in my azure entra id like this

```
data "azuread_groups" "current_ad_group" {
  return_all = true
}

output "groupnames" {
  value = "${data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group.*.display_names}"
}
```

but since I need only two groups, I want to output only these two specific onces "Devops_IAC_Administrators", "Devops_IAC_Contributors".

I have tried something like this. Below is in data.tf file

```
data "azuread_groups" "current_ad_group" {
  # return_all = true
  for_each =  distinct(flatten(var.groups))
  display_names = each.value
  security_enabled  = true
}
```

and Below is in main.tf files

```
locals {
  group_display_names = [for group in data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group : group.display_name]

}

output "groupnames" {
  value = local.group_display_names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `groups` is a map, the flatten function will error out with something like:

```txt
Call to function "flatten" failed: can only flatten lists, sets and tuples.
```

---

You have to extract the values from the groups, we can do that with a for loop:

```hcl
variable "groups" {
  type = map(list(string))

  default = {
    "Infrastructure Contributors" = [
      "Devops_IAC_Administrators"
    ],
    "Application_Contributors" = [
      "Devops_IAC_Administrators",
      "Devops_IAC_Contributors"
    ]
  }
}

locals {
  groups_flat = toset(flatten([for k, v in var.groups : v]))
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = local.groups_flat
  triggers = { x = each.value }
}
```

If you look closely you will notice that instead of the `distinct` I'm using `toset` they work on the same exact principle, but the set seems to plays better in `for_each` loops.

And a terraform plan will show us:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.test["Devops_IAC_Administrators"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "x" = "Devops_IAC_Administrators"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.test["Devops_IAC_Contributors"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "x" = "Devops_IAC_Contributors"
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: without making my varibale as you have wrote above I can achieve the same output with making a  local variable like  `locals {
  groups_test = distinct(flatten([for key in var.groups : key ]))
}` and output  `output "name_test" {
  value = local.groups_test
}`  `variable  "groups" {
  default = {}
}`   my problem is that I can not pass this to `data "azuread_groups" "current_ad_group" `

Comment: @play_something_good I was testing and the `distinct` was giving me some troubles, I modified by answer to use `toset` instead, see if that gets you where you need to be